# How to build an object of friends and likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is partially a javascript technique question. I am trying to build an object with facebook id as the key, and an array of likes as the value. My issue is the in my innermost function, I cannot access the variable fbid that I need for setting the key.

How to get access to fbid in the scope of the inner anonymous function?

```
friendsLikes = [];
FB.api('/me/friends',function(friends){
    for(var i=0;i<friends.data.length;i++){
        var fbid = friends.data[i].id
        FB.api(fbid+'/likes',function(likes){
            if(likes.data.length>=1){
                            //this is where I build the object
                            //I cannot use fbid for the key :(
                console.log(likes.data.length);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `fbid` is updated on each iteration, before your callback executes.

- Loop through friends list
- Set `fbid` to the friend's ID
- Initiate an async call to get that friend's likes
- Continue to next friend until we loop through the entire list
- Some time passes
- Results come back from the server and callbacks begin executing.  At this point, `fbid` is the same for all callbacks – specifically, it is set to the  ID of the last friend in the list.

Here's how I'd capture the `fbid` of each iteration:

```
friendsLikes = [];
FB.api('/me/friends',function(friends){
    for(var i=0;i<friends.data.length;i++){
        var fbid = friends.data[i].id
        FB.api(fbid+'/likes', function(fbid) { return function(likes){
            if(likes.data.length>=1){
                            // `fbid` will be correct here
                console.log(likes.data.length);
            }
        }}(fbid));
    }
});
```

Notice that we use a self-executing function and pass the current `fbid`.  This returns a function that will have the proper `fbid` in scope.

---

And now a note on how you're doing this: this code's performance is going to suck because you're paying for a HTTP roundtrip for each friend.  Remember that a browser will only open somewhere between 2-8 connections per host (depending on browser), and all of these calls are going to *graph.facebook.com*.

With a modest friend list of 200 and a generous roundtrip time of 150ms, the *theoretical best case* scenario is ~4 seconds.  Things quickly go downhill if the browser will only do 2 concurrent connections and we have a 200ms roundtrip time: 20 seconds.

It's also highly likely Facebook might rate-limit you at some point.

Instead, you need to use the [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', { batch: [
    { method: 'GET', relative_url: id+'/likes' },
    ...
] }, function(r) {
    // `r` will be an array of results for each item in `batch`
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the second part of your answer, about performance.

Comment: Of course.  It's a good rule of thumb to say to yourself "I might want to rethink this" if you're ever firing off AJAX requests from a loop.  There's usually a better way.